# Displaying json data using browser window in electron

Tags: push-notification, electron

I am using Electron Browser window to display notifications received from firebase.

```
My sample.js file        
 ipcRenderer.on(NOTIFICATION_RECEIVED, (_, serverNotificationPayload) => {

          if (serverNotificationPayload.notification.body)
        {
        showCustomNotification(serverNotificationPayload);
    }

function showCustomNotification(serverNotificationPayload){
    let disp = electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay()
    console.log(disp.bounds.x)
    console.log(disp.bounds.y)
    win = new BrowserWindow({
    x: disp.bounds.width-310,
    y: disp.bounds.height-620,
    width: 300,
    height: 550,
    icon: './icon.png',
    title: serverNotificationPayload.notification.title,
    closable: true,
    skipTaskbar: true,
    show: true,
    frame:false,
    alwaysOnTop: true
    })

    win.loadFile('index.html');
```

Now in my index.html file I need to render the json data thats received from firebase.I tried several solutions but none worked.If somebody can help me it would be great.Whenever I broadcast messages through firebase ,an empty window opens .I want to display the json content in that window.

Comment: Would be helpful if you specify what solutions you've already tried. From your code above, it doesn't seem like you're doing anything with the `serverNotificationPayload` except setting the notification title, but then you're also setting the `frame` to `false`. Try flipping that to `true` to see if the title shows up.

Comment: @Neil I will try that Thank you :)

Comment: @Neil In my Json data I have body,title and a message .Is it possible to display in the browser window created?

Comment: It would be possible. After you create your `win` BrowserWindow, use it to send the payload to your HTML (eg: `win.webContents.send('serverPayLoad', serverNotificationPayload);`). Then on `index.html`'s script; receive it: `ipcRenderer.on('serverPayLoad', (event, arg) => { ... });` And in the renderer function, you could set the payload's contents to any DOM element.